# Grub error "Can't allocate Kernal" when using the linux command

Tags: grub2

I had a boot failure and am trying to use grub to recover.
My boot partition is (hd6,gpt3), which I set as root.
the grub command linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-75-generic root=/dev/sdg3 results in "error: can't allocate kernel"
I cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: Does a configfile entry work to boot grub.cfg? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54&p=13788092#post13788092 Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair If/when you run fix from Boot-Repair only use advanced mode, so you can choose an install & drive to install grub into. With multiple drives, default may not be what you want.